# How to loop through this JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a script that post a variable and get a JSON as result. This is the script:

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('Admin/get_memo_by_surat'); ?>',{data:id},function(result){
   alert(result);
});
```

When I do alert if the script success post the variable, I get this JSON :

```
[{"no_dokumen":"19\/0001-1\/SCG","dari":"PPC","pic":"77973035","kepada":"PPC","instruksi":"Mas Dwi tolong hps","tanggal_dist":"2017-03-27 13:31:53","tanggal_proses":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"no_dokumen":"19\/0002-1\/SCG","dari":"PPC","pic":"77973035","kepada":"PMD","instruksi":"Test to PMD","tanggal_dist":"2017-03-27 13:32:15","tanggal_proses":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

I've tried using `$.each`, but it show nothing.

```
$.each(result, function(i,response){ alert(response.no_dokumen); });
```

So, how do I loop through this? I'd like to represent this data in a table by the way.

Comment: it should work can you create a demo?

Comment: It looks good and works for me: if I declare `result` equal to this JSON object and then use your `$.each`. Just make sure that you deserialize JSON into object before trying to iterate through it.

Comment: @guradio sorry, I have limited acces to this site only right now. Can't create demo.

Comment: @ashura91 you can see the button `<>` create the demo

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/27vaspm6/. Please check the console for errors

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: the alert is not working in my code. How strange.
@YeldarKurmangaliyev what do you mean by deserialize  json?

Comment: If your JSON is a string you should call `JSON.parse(yourJsonString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this result variable contain json data but string. 
you just add the new line:

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
```

and then try,

```
$.each(data, function(i, response){ alert(response.no_dokumen); });
```